# Free jQuery Fileupload control with progressbar

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, asp-classic

I am aware of jQuery plugin for fileuploader with progressbar. Are you aware of anyone that is free? I want this plugin for a classic-asp website.

Comment: I am not aware of any such jQuery plugin that isn't free.  How about an example of the one you see that costs money?

Comment: For example, Uploadify is a jquery plugin. But it needs licensing cost.Of course the amount is very little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) is a flash based uploader that works with asp. [Here is a tutorial](http://www.uploadify.quickersite.com/r/) that I have found that shows an example of how to set it up.

[Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) is another great file uploader plugin that I have used. I am sure you can get it to work with asp as well.